# Why is this not valid, but works locally? — The king's race problem in codeforces

Tags: c++

Could someone help a new c++ learner?

I'm trying to solve the king's race probem at https://codeforces.com/contest/1075/problem/A

Definition of the problem:

White king sits at point (1,1) and black king sits at point defined by first input, so (n,n). The first input also defines the board size.

The next two inputs define the point where both of the kings will race and the first one to get to that point wins. Naturally white king moves always first. However, in this problem, kings can stand in adjacent cells or even in the same cell at the same time.

Expected output should be the color of the king that wins the race.

Problem is when giving inputs `719386363530333627 620916440917452264 265151985453132665`

Expected output is black and I can confirm this running the code locally, but when running the code through codeforces testing set, it fails to give the right answer by outputting white.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
     // take inputs
     long long board_length;
     long long price_coordinate_x;
     long long price_coordinate_y;

     cin >> board_length;
     cin >> price_coordinate_x;
     cin >> price_coordinate_y;

     // starting points for kings
     int white_x = 1;
     int white_y = 1;
     long long black_x = board_length;
     long long black_y = board_length;

     // Difference between price coordinate points
     long long point_difference_white = labs(price_coordinate_x-price_coordinate_y); 
     long long point_difference_black = labs(price_coordinate_x-price_coordinate_y);

     // if x > y => y will be the first value we'll reach
     if (price_coordinate_x > price_coordinate_y) {
          point_difference_white += labs(white_x-price_coordinate_y);
          point_difference_black += labs(black_x-price_coordinate_x); 
     }
     else if (price_coordinate_x < price_coordinate_y) {
          point_difference_white += labs(white_x-price_coordinate_x);
          point_difference_black += labs(black_y-price_coordinate_y);
     }
     else {
          point_difference_white += labs(white_x-price_coordinate_x);
          point_difference_black += labs(black_x-price_coordinate_x);
     }

     if (point_difference_black >= point_difference_white) {
          cout << "White" << endl;
     }
     else if (point_difference_black < point_difference_white) {
          cout << "Black" << endl;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: What input and what is your expected output?

Comment: It looks like the inputs are 64-bit integers, but `long int` could be 32-bit or higher - [C data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types). I would recommend using `long long` instead.

Comment: My bad.

Here's the actual problem that i'm figuring out:

[link]https://codeforces.com/contest/1075/problem/A

It should calculate which king is going to get to a certain point in the board first, when white king is always located at the point (1,1) and the black king is located at the point defined by first input.

I changed the long ints to long longs and got a little further. 
Fails with inputs
`719386363530333627 620916440917452264 265151985453132665` 
where it should give the output black but for some reason gives white.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Good catch, `white_y` is actually unnecessary for the code to work, since both `white_y` and `white_x` have the same value. White king always starts its journey from point (1,1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `std::labs()` which uses `long` integers.
A `long` integer is most probably 32 bits on the target system.

This means that your 64 bit `long long` variables will not get the correct result for *big* values.

The easy fix to get the correct result is to use `std::llabs()`.

You may also want to consider using types with fixed width, like `std::int64_t` - or go with the biggest signed integer: `std::intmax_t`.

`<cinttypes>` declares these `abs` functions for `std::intmax_t`:

```
std::intmax_t abs( std::intmax_t n );
std::intmax_t imaxabs( std::intmax_t n );
```

Answer (score 1):

As was suggested by Ted it got accepted by codeforces when replaced the labs functions to llabs functions. Thanks for the help. I'm pretty sure this can be written using a better approach, so that's what I'm going to do next. Anyways, thanks.

Final code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    // take inputs
    long long board_length;
    long long price_coordinate_x;
    long long price_coordinate_y;

    cin >> board_length;
    cin >> price_coordinate_x;
    cin >> price_coordinate_y;

    // starting points for kings
    int white_x = 1;
    int white_y = 1;
    long long black_x = board_length;
    long long black_y = board_length;

    // Difference between price coordinate points
    long long point_difference_white = llabs(price_coordinate_x-price_coordinate_y); 
    long long point_difference_black = llabs(price_coordinate_x-price_coordinate_y);

    // if x > y => y will be the first value we'll reach
    if (price_coordinate_x > price_coordinate_y) {
        point_difference_white += llabs(white_x-price_coordinate_y);
        point_difference_black += llabs(black_x-price_coordinate_x); 
    }
    else if (price_coordinate_x < price_coordinate_y) {
        point_difference_white += llabs(white_x-price_coordinate_x);
        point_difference_black += llabs(black_y-price_coordinate_y);
    }
    else {
        point_difference_white += llabs(white_x-price_coordinate_x);
        point_difference_black += llabs(black_x-price_coordinate_x);
    }

    if (point_difference_black >= point_difference_white) {
        cout << "White" << endl;
    }
    else if (point_difference_black < point_difference_white) {
        cout << "Black" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's also a cleaner solution with better logic, since the larger value from the difference of `(price_x, starting_point_x)` and `(price_y, starting_point_y)` will represent the total number of steps needed to get to that position.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    // take inputs
    long long board_length;
    long long price_coordinate_x;
    long long price_coordinate_y;

    cin >> board_length;
    cin >> price_coordinate_x;
    cin >> price_coordinate_y;

    // starting points for kings
    int white_x_y = 1;
    long long black_x_y = board_length;

    long long white_diff_x = llabs(price_coordinate_x-white_x_y);
    long long white_diff_y = llabs(price_coordinate_y-white_x_y);

    long long black_diff_x = llabs(price_coordinate_x-black_x_y);
    long long black_diff_y = llabs(price_coordinate_y-black_x_y);

    long long steps_white = max(white_diff_x,white_diff_y);
    long long steps_black = max(black_diff_x,black_diff_y);

    if (steps_black >= steps_white) {
        cout << "White" << endl;
    }
    else if (steps_black < steps_white) {
        cout << "Black" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```